# Data extensions used in Journey builder - how to append data

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions

During my Journey the data extension fields are getting updated with information that is then used in the decision splits : 5 fields reflecting the links on which the customer has clicked for ex
in the Data extension, I need a field that concatenates all this information so a field that is "appended" regularly during the journey so I can then use it to populate the description of the lead

Is there a way to append data to a field already containing information in the Data extension?  update customer seems to replace but not append
Is this something where I would need an SQL query and automation studio or is there a simpler solution ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [data binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) syntax to update data extension field

1. Let's say the field in your Journey Builder Data extension is called "logs"
2. Go to Entry Source tab, click on the entry source, take a note of Event Definite Key, for example: Event123456
3. Use below syntax in "Update Contacts" tile,  separate by a space, "ExtraDetails" is the new content you want to "append" to the field:

> {{Event.Event123456.logs}} ExtraDetails

Once it is executed in the Journey, you should see it is updated in the DE row.

Comment: i have nevery used this data binding syntax, so this might be a very stupid question, based on what you are saying I can use this syntax directly in the update contact tile of the Journey builder ?

Comment: Yes, on the left select the field you want to update, enter above value in the right textbox

Comment: ok - then for the entry source tab, I need to put my data extension in there also or is there a way to reference the data extension field without using the entry source tab ?  (I am very much a beginner on this side of thing - thank you for your patience)

Comment: I don’t think you can reference DE field without entry source definition key. I tired with DE customer key before it is not working.